# Add meta content attribute with JQuery or CSS (or maybe with another technique) in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I should add an empty content attribute (content="") with JQuery in the following line (in a wordpress html posting document) (note: the line is NOT within the  if this is important somehow ...):

```
<meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage"/>
```

So, the end result should be exactly this line:

```
<meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" content="" itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage"/>
```

It exist a better solution as JQuery (because the machines could not read JavaScript or so), I am open for all ...

Thank you very much for all suggestions/solutions in advance!

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't use JavaScript to form your structured data as it is discouraged by search engines. This is something the back end needs to take care of properly.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I can change the related PHP somehow ...

Comment: Solved in the backend! Thank you again!

Comment: For documentation, I've posted this as anser. Can you verify? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is to solve this issue directly in the back end, as it is discouraged by search engines to use JavaScript to form you structured data.

Although Google is more and more implementing ways to dynamically (thus with JavaScript) crawl through your site, I advice you to take the safe road and fix this within your back end logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `attr` method

```
$("meta[property='itemprop=mainEntityOfPage']").attr("content", "");
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that as first help solution, then I will try to fix the source (php).

Comment: Unfortunately this has not worked. The line has not changed.